# Unit conversions menu

Tags: c++

I need to create a conversion program with 5 choices ("Main menu") of conversions. Each choices must have atleast 10 conversions in it. i have already written the "Main menu", but im struggling with the conversions options. i do not know how to connect it with the main menu. here is my code, please help me edit it if possible. (sorry for my bad english).

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double mm, cm, m, km, in, ft, yd, mi;
    long double mm1, cm1, m1, km1, in1, ft1, yd1, mi1;
    char choice, mainmenu;
    int b, c;
    loop:
    {
mainmenu:
    {
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Available Conversions\n";
    cout << "1- Length\n";
    cout << "2- Volume\n";
    cout << "3- Temperature\n";
    cout << "4- Power\n";
    cout << "5- Length\n";
    cout << "6- Exit\n";
    cin >> choice;
    }
    
switch(choice)
   {
    case 1://Length
    cout << "a. kilometer to mile\n";
    cout << "b. mile to kilometer\n";
    cout << "c. feet to inches\n";
    cout << "d. inches to feet\n";
    cout << "e. yard to meter\n";
    cout << "f. meter to yard\n";
    cout << "g. mile to feet\n";
    cout << "h. feet to mile\n";
    cout << "i. meter to inches\n";
    cout << "j. inches to meter\n";
    cout << "k. Back to Main menu\n";
   }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Before you get any further: Try to avoid `goto`.

Comment: ^ Rather use loops, and / or function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function with a loop for validation  and a `switch` statement with a `case` for each menu item. Make a function for each menu item and call it in the item's `case`, then `return` from the function. If the menu item's job is another menu, do the same thing again: validation loop, `switch`, more function calls.

This keeps all of the functions small, easy to understand, and easy to test. When you're a little more experienced with C++ you'll find better ways (like data structures that link input tokens to functions to call) so you can reuse the menu loop, but for now Keep It Simple.

Example menu:

```cpp
void main_menu()
{
    while (true) // loop forever. The return statements later will exit the function 
                 // and the loop when a good input is processed.
    {
        int option; // use appropriate input data type
        std::cout << "Please provide input: ";
        // more detailed menu option description goes here if you want one.
        if (std::cin >> option) // Always test user input.
                                // The users that aren't morons are trying to hack your 
                                // program. Never trust a user.
        {
            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                    do_main_menu_option_1(); // Call a function that does whatever 
                                             // option 1 is supposed to do
                    return; // leave function and loop.
                case 2:
                    do_main_menu_option_2();
                    return; 
                case 3:
                    do_main_menu_option_3();
                    return; 
                default:
                    std::cout << "Invalid input. Please try again." << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid input. Please input a number." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear(); // clear input error flag
            std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
                              // discard garbage input.
        }
    }
}
```